# How to get the selected values on a select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a multiple select input.
I am getting the values from a remote database, as follows:

```
  <select class="form-control select2" id="tor" name="tor[]" style="width: 100%;"height: 150pt" multiple>

        <?php   if ($result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlBU))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {


    printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);


            printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[8]);
            echo '<option value='.$row[0].' selected>'.$row[7].' '.$row[8].'</option>';


    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
     ?>           

                    </select>
```

I need to pass the selected rows as an array to perform other actions.

I am getting the values as follows:

```
 $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

        var tor = []; 
        $('#tor :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
          tor[i] = $(selected).text(); 
        });
        alert (foo);


    location.href = "tor_create_revisions.php?id=" + tor




    });
```

Using this script I am getting an array with the selected rows, but the output is the values of :

'.$row[7].' '.$row[8].'

and I need the values of $row[0].

What should I change?

Thank you

Comment: `$(selected).val();`

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you. May be you want to put it as answer.